# Появление и исчезание div блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на `#block1`, `.block2` появлялся и исчезал.
Сделать это надо на jquery.

Comment: `.block2` должен исчезать сам или после следующего клика?

Comment: После следующего клика

Comment: Вы бы хоть сами попытались. А то звучит, как техзадание на fl.ru

Comment: очень рад за вас. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что автору следует попытаться решить задачу своими силами, а не просить решить задачу за него!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это почти канонический пример применения *jQuery*. Можно сказать *Hello, world* на *jQuery*.

```
$('#block1').on('click', function() {
    $('.block2').toggle();
});
```

Гораздо интереснее задача (которая нередко встречается) отображения и скрытия соседнего элемента или элемента, который находится в одном контейнере с "кнопкой"

См. также:

- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Мне надо сделать примерно так: блок1.клик(функция(){если(блок2 видно){}блок2.скрыть}иначе{блок2.показать});

Comment: Я не просто так привел ссылки. Посмотрите на параметры метода `toggle()`, в частности последний вариант.

Comment: Хорошо спасибо Вам. Я просто только учусь программировать и даже не знаю как это в гугле искать могу только своими словами.

Comment: @Ezdrael Почитайте, хотя бы бегло, документацию _jQuery_ или найдите ее перевод, если по-английски сложно читать. Также можно поискать учебники на русском языке. Только нужно понимать, что они часто написаны для старых версий, но общий подход сохранился.

Comment: Спасибо Вам ищо раз, я уже нашёл русскую версию http://jquery-docs.ru/Effects/toggle/